# How to achieve the Adobe XD background blur effect in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, adobe-xd

I need to apply a background blur effect in Adobe XD to iOS with those properties. I try with UIBlurEffect and UIVibrancyEffect too but can not achieve that result.

[image]
[image]

How can I do? Thanks!!